# rolling calculation targetting html contents

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have some markup as follows which shows a historical view of payments with the most recent at the top. I am trying to show what the balance was in each row at the time which that payment was accrued...

```
<div class="row">
<div class="payment-description">Payment #3</div>
<div class="payment-earned">£0.30</div>
<div class="payment-amount"></div>
<div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="payment-description">Payment #2</div>
<div class="payment-earned">£0.20</div>
<div class="payment-amount"></div>
<div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="payment-description">Payment #1</div>
<div class="payment-earned">£0.10</div>
<div class="payment-amount"></div>
<div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>
```

I have following javascript as follows which will show the combined present balance but need some help as to how to target by the particluar row given that all classes are the same and i can't add ID's. I'm not sure if previousElementSibling could be used?

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
var sum = 0;
var i;
$(".payment-earned").each(function() {
        var val = $.trim( $(this).text() );
        if ( val ) {
            val = parseFloat( val.replace( /^\£/, "" ) );
            sum += !isNaN( val ) ? val : 0;
        }
    });
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = (sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

CURRENT

earned----paid----balance

---

£0.30-------0-------£0.60

£0.20-------0-------£0.60

£0.10-------0-------£0.60

DESIRED

earned----paid----balance

---

£0.30-------0-------£0.60

£0.20-------0-------£0.30

£0.10-------0-------£0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a second loop, you can profit from the `index` variable of the `.each` callback to update the balance respectively with the iterated `payment`.

And to calculate the `sum` of the balance the way you want you need to loop over the elements in a reverse order, using `$($(".payment-earned").get().reverse())`.

This is how should be your code:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
var sum = 0;
$($(".payment-earned").get().reverse()).each(function(index) {
  var val = $.trim($(this).text());
  if (val) {
    val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\£/, ""));
    sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
  }
  x[(x.length - 1) - index].innerHTML = (sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
var sum = 0;
$($(".payment-earned").get().reverse()).each(function(index) {
  var val = $.trim($(this).text());
  if (val) {
    val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\£/, ""));
    sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
  }
  x[(x.length - 1) - index].innerHTML = (sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
.payment-earned, .payment-amount, .demo.payment-balance{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="payment-description">Payment #3</div>
  <div class="payment-earned">£0.30</div>
  <div class="payment-amount"></div>
  <div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="payment-description">Payment #2</div>
  <div class="payment-earned">£0.20</div>
  <div class="payment-amount"></div>
  <div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="payment-description">Payment #1</div>
  <div class="payment-earned">£0.10</div>
  <div class="payment-amount"></div>
  <div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Alternative:**

For better performance and more readability you can avoid the `x[(x.length-1)-index]` calculation by using:

```
$(this).parent().find('.demo').html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

```js
var sum = 0;
$($(".payment-earned").get().reverse()).each(function(index) {
  var val = $.trim($(this).text());
  if (val) {
    val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\£/, ""));
    sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
  }
  $(this).parent().find('.demo').html(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
.payment-earned, .payment-amount, .demo.payment-balance{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="payment-description">Payment #3</div>
  <div class="payment-earned">£0.30</div>
  <div class="payment-amount"></div>
  <div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="payment-description">Payment #2</div>
  <div class="payment-earned">£0.20</div>
  <div class="payment-amount"></div>
  <div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="payment-description">Payment #1</div>
  <div class="payment-earned">£0.10</div>
  <div class="payment-amount"></div>
  <div class="demo payment-balance"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i don't think this is quite doing what i'm after as it's replicating the value of any row in isolation - it should add the current row to any rows underneath giving the total up to that point in that row

Comment: @PaulSmith My bad I updated my answer, you should loop the elements in areverse order with `$($(".payment-earned").get().reverse())` to calculate and append the `sum` the way you want. this will give you what you need.

Comment: I've not got the rep to upvote your answer but worked great so many thanks